# How do I get the newest updates to Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

According to https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/release-notes, Docker has been upgraded to version 18.06.1 as of October 18. Yet, I'm still seeing 17.12.0 in our instance.

Specifically I'm seeing these messages that seem to contradict the release notes when I run `cloud-build-local`:

```
2018/10/29 16:47:24 Warning: The server docker version installed (18.06.1-ce) is different from the one used in GCB (17.12.0-ce)
2018/10/29 16:47:24 Warning: The client docker version installed (18.06.1-ce) is different from the one used in GCB (17.12.0-ce)
```

I've tried Googling, reading all the quickstarts, how-tos, and concepts pages, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to upgrade/restart/install the patch to get the newest Docker version.

Will someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current hosted version is indeed 18.06.1 as noted in the Release Notes, but we forgot to push out a corresponding update to `cloud-build-local`. We've got an update in process, but the new distribution with cloud SDK won't be released until January. In the meantime, if you want to upgrade your `cloud-build-local`, you can download the upcoming release from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-local/tree/v0.4.3

We've updated our internal process to ensure that we keep the version check in `cloud-build-local` more in sync going forward, and as noted you can watch https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120854133 for progress toward the next release.

Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the bug report!

(I'm the Tech Lead for Google Cloud Build.)

Comment: FYI: Cloud SDK version 229.0.0 is scheduled for release tomorrow (January 8); you can watch the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) for updates.

Answer (score 3):

I found a Google Cloud issue referencing your issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120854133

I would keep an eye on that to find out more regarding it. I will also provide updates here if I find any.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to the process of reporting GCP bugs :)